# Meaning of Parameters in BackgroundSubtractorGMG Algorithm in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction

I am studying the GMG background subtraction algorithm as described in [this paper](http://goldberg.berkeley.edu/pubs/acc-2012-visual-tracking-final.pdf). As OpenCV 3.0 also has an implementation of the GMG algorithm (as the additional package opencv_contrib), I try to study the two together. However, I am not quite sure about the meaning of the two parameters `maxFeatures` and `quantizationLevels`, as I want to map them to the descriptions in the paper.

Quoting the source code in OpenCV 3.0 (file modules\bgsegm\src\bgfg_gmg.cpp):

```
//! Total number of distinct colors to maintain in histogram.
int maxFeatures;
```

and

```
//! Number of discrete levels in each channel to be used in histograms.
int quantizationLevels;
```

And quoting the paper (Section II B) (with some mathematical symbol and variable names modified since LaTex is not supported here):

"... Of the T observed features, select the F_tot <= F_max most recently observed unique features; let I is a subset of {1, 2, ... T}, where |I| = F_tot, be the corresponding time index set. (If T > F_max, it is possible that F_tot, the number of distinct features observed, exceeds the limit F_max. In that case, we throw away the oldest observations so that F_tot <= F_max). Then, we calculate an average to generate the initial histogram: H(T) = (1/F_tot)∑f(r). This puts equal weight, 1/F_tot, in F_tot unique bins of the histogram."

From the above description, I was originally convinced that `maxFeatures` in OpenCV 3.0 refers to F_max in the paper, and `quantizationLevels` refers to F_tot. However, this does not sound right for two reasons: (1) The paper mentions "F_tot is the number of distinct features observed", and (2) the OpenCV source code does not pose any relationship between `maxFeatures` and `quantizationLevels`, while the paper clearly suggests that the former should be larger than or equal to the latter.

So, what are the meaning of `maxFeatures` and `quantizationLevels`? And is `quantizationLevels` a parameter introduced by OpenCV for the calculation of histogram?

Answer (score 2):

After further studying the source code in OpenCV, I believe that `maxFeatures` refer to F_max in the paper, while `quantizationLevels` is actually the number of bins in the histogram. The reason is as follows:

In the function `insertFeature()`, which contains the following code:

```
static bool insertFeature(unsigned int color, float weight, unsigned int* colors, float* weights, int& nfeatures, int maxFeatures)
{
    int idx = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nfeatures; ++i) {
        if (color == colors[i]) {
            // feature in histogram
            weight += weights[i];
            idx = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (idx >= 0) {                          // case 1
        // move feature to beginning of list
        ::memmove(colors + 1, colors, idx * sizeof(unsigned int));
        ::memmove(weights + 1, weights, idx * sizeof(float));
        colors[0] = color;
        weights[0] = weight;
    }
    else if (nfeatures == maxFeatures) {     // case 2
        // discard oldest feature
        ::memmove(colors + 1, colors, (nfeatures - 1) * sizeof(unsigned int));
        ::memmove(weights + 1, weights, (nfeatures - 1) * sizeof(float));
        colors[0] = color;
        weights[0] = weight;
    }
    else {                                   // case 3
        colors[nfeatures] = color;
        weights[nfeatures] = weight;
        ++nfeatures;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Case 1: When the color matches one item in the array `colors[]`, the corresponding array element is obtained.

Case 2: When the color does not match any item in the array `colors[]` and `maxFeatures` is reached (`nFeatures` stores the number of items stored in the array), then the oldest feature is removed for the new color.

Case 3: When the color does not match any item in the array `colors[]` and `maxFeatures` is not reached yet, add the color to a new item of the array, and `nFeatures` is incremented by 1.

Hence `maxFeatures` should correspond to F_max (the maximum number of features) in the paper.

In addition, in the function `apply()`:

```
static unsigned int apply(const void* src_, int x, int cn, double minVal, double maxVal, int quantizationLevels)
{
    const T* src = static_cast<const T*>(src_);
    src += x * cn;

    unsigned int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0, shift = 0; i < cn; ++i, ++src, shift += 8)
        res |= static_cast<int>((*src - minVal) * quantizationLevels / (maxVal - minVal)) << shift;

    return res;
}
```

This function maps the pixel's color intensity pointed to by the pointer `src_` to a bin according to the values of `maxVal`, `minVal` and `quantizationLevels`, such that if `quantizationLevels` = q, the result of the code:

```
static_cast<int>((*src - minVal) * quantizationLevels / (maxVal - minVal))
```

must be an integer in the range [0, q-1]. However, there can be `cn` channels (for example, in RGB, `cn` = 3, hence the shift operation and the possible number of bins (denote it as b) is therefore `quantizationLevels` to the power of `cn`. So if b > F_max, we have to discard the (b - F_max) oldest features.

Hence, in OpenCV, if we set `maxFeatures` to be >= `quantizationLevels` ^ `cn`, we never have to discard the oldest features, because we allow more than enough bins, or more than enough different unique features.